# Using a Class/record in an other class (subtype mark required in this context)

Tags: class, oop, record, ada, subtype

I want to learn ADA and have a problem with the 'class'

I have 2 classes A and B and want that class A can use class B.
Class A

```
with B;
package A is
   type A is tagged
      record
         varA : INTEGER := 0;
         varB : INTEGER := 0;
      end record;
   procedure DOSMTH(A_In : in out A; B_IN: in out B);

end A;
```

and Class B

```
package B is
   type B is tagged
      record
         var1 : INTEGER;
         var2 : INTEGER;
      end record;
      procedure DoSMTH2(B_IN: in out B; var  : INTEGER);
end B;
```

If I want to compile A I get following error message:

> subtype mark required in this context
>   found 'B' declared at b.ads:1

Another problem is my 'Main' File which can't use A and B (declaration)

```
with Ada.Text_IO, A, B;
procedure Main is
   a : A;
   b : B;
begin
 null;  
end Main;
```

I get following Errors:

> object "A" cannot be used before end of its declaration
>   object "B" cannot be used before end of its declaration

I can't find any solution for that. I have read the ADA 2005 Reference Manual but can't find anything.

OK thx for the help,
finaly it works now.

Solution:

Modify Class A to

```
 with B;
    package A is
       type A is tagged
          record
             -- u can use  a object VAR with
             -- objB : B.B
             varA : INTEGER := 0;
             varB : INTEGER := 0;
          end record;
       procedure DOSMTH(A_In : in out A; B_IN: in out B.B);

    end A
```

Modify Main to:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, A, B;
procedure Main is
   myA : A.A; --the old one was stupid ...
   myB : B.B; --same here
begin
 null;  
end Main;
```

Comment: The `package` concept of Ada is not equivalent to the `class` concept in other languages.  I think you need to find a tutorial that explains Ada for people coming from Java/C#/C++ or other OO languages.  Maybe someone else reading this can point to one.

Comment: hm ok :-( i only found this Document: http://d.feneuille.free.fr/ada-java-00-comp.pdf which is trying to compare JAVA OOP with ADA.

Comment: @user3554951 Here is (incomplete) list of books about Ada with links to some of them https://gist.github.com/darkestkhan/11136936 , most of the free (my personal pick is "Ada for Software Engineers" by M. Ben Ari)

Comment: Also name is Ada (it is ladies name, not acronym, and certainly not Americans with Disabilities Act nor Australian Dental Association; lets make life easy for people that will do case sensitive google query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only withed package B in package A - in order to use anything form it you have to use qualified name (that is: for record B you should use B.B). Like:

`with B;
package A is
   type A is tagged
      record
         varA : INTEGER := 0;
         varB : INTEGER := 0;
      end record;
   procedure DOSMTH(A_In : in out A; B_IN: in out B.B);
end A;`

If you want to use things declared in package B without fully qualifying name you should put `use B;` right after withing it.

As to whether one should use or only with package is hard question - most of the time most Ada programmers that I know (including myself) prefer to with packages only, rarely using them - for example when working with Lumen library (OpenGL binding with glut-like functionality) I usually use Lumen because then I can type GL.Whatever_GL_Function instead of Lumen.GL.Whatever_GL_Function (but I do not "use" Lumen.GL). If package name is long I prefer to rename it inside procedure and in case of types (for operators if defined) one can `use type B.B;`

PS: I can elaborate more if some parts of it are unclear.

Comment: Thx for your answer, Now i get in my main Program 'A' is not visible i don't know. I looks like this example program: http://www.infres.enst.fr/~pautet/Ada95/chap22.htm ( e_c22_p2.ada,  e_c22_p3.ada)

Comment: hm ok, i edit my comment. Now i have A.A and B.B and it works. but the main Program throws the same error. object A cannot be used... A  but i declare a : A.A. Why it's still using only A?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the main program is that Ada isn’t case-sensitive, so when you say

```
a : A.A;
```

the compiler sees as far as `a : A` and thinks that the second A is the same thing as the first, hence the complaint that `object "A" cannot be used before end of its declaration`.

You can tell the compiler where to look for the package `A` by qualifying it. Package `A` is declared at library level, and there’s a notional package `Standard` you can use to indicate this:

```
a : Standard.A.A;
```

However, it’s much better, if you can, to avoid using the same name for different things in the first place.

Comment: Thx. Now it compiles. I modified the question and added my new solution to solve this :-) thx for your help.

Comment: @user3554951 I second the comment about avoiding using the same name.  In some OO languages, the type (class) *is* the top-level module, but in Ada, that is definitely not the case.  You have a `package`, and a package can contain any number of `type`s (including zero).  So using the same name for a package and a type is confusing and leads to errors, and Ada programmers just don't do that.  You might want to change the package names to `A_Package` and `B_Package`, which might help you while you're learning the language.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that the compiler sees "B" as the name of the package and not the record. Try naming your package or records differently.

Also, if you want to learn Ada, the reference manual is the last place you want to start at. Get the book by Barnes or get one of the older books used at Amazon. You get good books about Ada 95 for 5$ in the used section.

Comment: Having package and type names identical is not cause of problem

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to help